# Configuring ACL in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, acl

I am using Oracle 11g and trying to execute following:

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL (
      acl           => 'sec_debt.xml',
      description   => 'Permissions to access GPC2',
      principal     => 'GPCPROD',
      is_grant      => TRUE,
      privilege     => 'connect');
   COMMIT;
END;
/

BEGIN
   DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL (
    acl          => 'sec_debt.xml',                
    host         => 'fraitcf1vd0959.de.db.com');
   COMMIT;
END;
/
```

I have received ACL created as `/sys/acls/sec_debt.xml`. I can see it in `DBA_NETWORK_ACLS`

```
select acl , host , lower_port , upper_port from DBA_NETWORK_ACLS;

/sys/acls/sec_debt.xml  fraitcf1vd0959.de.db.com   NULL NULL
```

I don't find any such directory (`/sys/acls/`) in my database server. Is there a way I can change this path? Or do I need to get this directory structure created in server? Request help.

Comment: The information is stored in the oracle XML DB repository - a set of table, not a physical file with that path on the server.  See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb16fol.htm#i1042509)  From a usage perspective, it is just a unique name to identify the acl.

Comment: Are you having a problem with this ACL? Is it not working as expected?